# Output text with both unigrams and bigrams in R

Tags: r, nlp, n-gram

I'm trying to figure out how to identify unigrams and bigrams in a text in R, and then keep both in the final output based on a threshold. I've done this in Python with gensim's Phraser model, but haven't figured out how to do it in R.

For example:

```
strings <- data.frame(text = 'This is a great movie from yesterday', 'I went to the movies', 'Great movie time at the theater', 'I went to the theater yesterday')
#Pseudocode below
bigs <- tokenize_uni_bi(strings, n = 1:2, threshold = 2)
print(bigs)
[['this', 'great_movie', 'yesterday'], ['went', 'movies'], ['great_movie', 'theater'], ['went', 'theater', 'yesterday']]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use quanteda framework for this:

```
library(quanteda)
# tokenize, tolower, remove stopwords and create ngrams
my_toks <- tokens(strings$text) 
my_toks <- tokens_tolower(my_toks)
my_toks <- tokens_remove(my_toks, stopwords("english"))
bigs <- tokens_ngrams(my_toks, n = 1:2)

# turn into document feature matrix and filter on minimum frequency of 2 and more
my_dfm <- dfm(bigs)
dfm_trim(my_dfm, min_termfreq = 2)

Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 6 features (50.0% sparse).
       features
docs    great movie yesterday great_movie went theater
  text1     1     1         1           1    0       0
  text2     0     0         0           0    1       0
  text3     1     1         0           1    0       1
  text4     0     0         1           0    1       1

# use convert function to turn this into a data.frame
```

Alternatively you could use tidytext package, tm, tokenizers etc etc. It all depends a bit on the output you are expecting.

An example using tidytext / dplyr looks like this:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
strings %>% 
  unnest_ngrams(bigs, text, n = 2, n_min = 1, ngram_delim = "_", stopwords = stopwords::stopwords()) %>% 
  count(bigs) %>% 
  filter(n >= 2)

         bigs n
1       great 2
2 great_movie 2
3       movie 2
4     theater 2
5        went 2
6   yesterday 2
```

Both quanteda and tidytext have a lot of online help available. See vignettes wiht both packages on cran.

Comment: Thank you @phiver! The second answer is exactly what I was looking for - should've looked harder in the tidytext documentation.

Comment: Just a footnote on this very good answer: `quanteda` supports/reexports `%>%` as well so `dplyr`-style chains are possible.